# Export Canvas to SVG without library

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working on a school project and I have hit a roadblock. In this project, we are not allowed to use any external libraries. We have a Canvas-element that is used as workspace for modeling ER-diagrams. We have to use the Canvas-element. Now we want to export everything in the canvas-element to a .SVG-picture. I've made it work with a .JPG-picture. But is there a way to convert the .JPG-picture to a .SVG-picture in Javascript?

Here is the code right now that exports the canvas to a .JPG-picture.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
    link.download = filename;
}
//picid is the id of the button that is used to export the picture.
//it doesn't work to just add .svg in the filename.
document.getElementById('picid').addEventListener('click', function(){
    downloadCanvas(this, 'myCanvas', 'picture.jpg');
}, false); 
});
```

The .JPG-picture is in BASE64-code.

Comment: I don't think so, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong. As far as I know the canvas is just pixels, while an SVG is a set of coordinates. Since you are drawing a diagram you probably have the coordinates so your best bet is to generate an svg out of those and use the canvas just as a visualization tool. The  export itself won't go through the canvas. Again, I hope someone proves me wrong.

Comment: I hope "*[you] want*" doesn't mean "*[you] have to*". It's probably feasible, but I guess you'll look at your school years with nostalgia when you'd have finished. @JonasGiuro is right. If you want an svg export, then produce an svg from your data. But raster to vector by hand is not an easy project.

Comment: Ahh, okey! I'll have to talk to my teacher then and explain that it won't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Pixels to SVG is possible and javascript can do it quickly. Quantize the image to a low colour count. trace out the pixels edges of matching colours. Pass a simplify filter on the path segments you get then dump the paths into a SVG element.